# jquery datatable table.fnGetData(rowIndex) not giving html tag's value

Tags: jquery, json, datatable, datatables, jquery-pagination

I am using jquery datatable. It has columns like input text box, dropdown select menu etc. Here is my function to get complete table's data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').submit(function(){
var table = $("#resultTable").dataTable();
var rows = talbe.dataTable().fnGetNodes();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var data= table.fnGetData(i);
            alert('data# '+data);
            console.log(data);
    }
alert(JSON.stringify(rows));

});
});
```

But I am getting data as

```
data# <input type="checkbox" name="selectA">", "<input type="text" name="city" value="Delhi" style="width: 87px;">",  "<select name="applicationNames[]" class="applicationNames"><option>optionA</option><option>optionB</option></select>
```

All i want is to get values entered in fields not html tags. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: I solved it as    var rows = $("#dbResultsTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   var cells = rows[i].cells;
         var select = cells[0].children[0].value; 
            if(cells[0].children[0].checked){
              select=cells[0].children[0].value; } else{
             select ='off';
            } } ............is there any simple way ??

Comment: You should post it as an answer and accept that answer yourself. Perhaps it will help other people in the future.

Comment: @davidkonrad: thanks for the suggestion will do that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it on my own here is the snippet

```
  var rows  $("#dbResultsTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
     var arr = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 
     var cells = rows[i].cells; 
     var select = cells[0].children[0].value;
    if(cells[0].children[0].checked){ 
       select=cells[0].children[0].value; 
     } else
    {
     select ='off';
     }
    }
```